# Apache NetBeans C Debugger Error - Not in executable format

Tags: c, netbeans-13

I have written, compiled and ran my C program with Apache NetBeans 13 just fine, but when I try to run the debugger I get the following error:

```
"C:\\Users\\username\\ ... \\ProblemaBombeiros\\dist\\Debug\\MinGW_1-Windows\\problemabombeiros.exe\": 
not in executable format: File format not recognized
```

But the file it found is indeed a executable format `.exe` .

Here are the configurations for the C/C++ build tools:

[image: Options]

Am I doing something wrong or do I need to do something else to start debugging?

Comment: What is that trailing `\\` doing in that program name?

Comment: "But the file it found is indeed a executable format .exe ." Did you run that program from shell? Or how do you know is valid? File extension `.exe` is not sufficient

Comment: I ran the program in the IDE, just pressed F6 and it compiled it. But I tested here in the cmd.exe and it runs strangely.  The program actually needs a txt file to work with. In NetBeans it appears to recognize this file but with the cmd it doesn't. Should I store this .txt file with the .exe one? (Edit: I added the txt file in the same directory as the .exe. It runs fine in the cmd but still netbeans is having a hard time with the debugger - Error 2).